# Apache kafka storm, persistence during maintenance

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have Ubuntu 14.04TS. I use *Node.js->Kafka->Storm->MongoDB* chain. With initial development, everything goes well. Messages are finally stored into mMngoDB.

In Kafka, I have one Zookeeper and broker0 in kakfa1. broker1 in kafka2. With Storm, Zookeeper, nimbus, and DRPC are located at storm1. Supervisor and worker are located at storm2.

Now the questions is when I do update storm1 and storm2. I stopped all processes of storm1 and storm2. I suppose Kafka will buffer the message from Node.js. After I restarted both storm1 and storm2, and redeployed topology, I found messages during storm1 storm2's, down and up, are lost. So indeed, Kafka does not keep persistence of messages during storm maintenance period.

In my mind, Kafka will remember the last index of the message it receive acknowledgement.

In all, how could I prevent message from lost when storm is under maintenance.

Comment: how much space had you allocated for kafka store messages?

Comment: Hi, I will close this question since I will give much more detail question, most focused.

Comment: mongodb and nodejs are useless details. Your problem must be somewhere in kafka or the storm spout. In my setup kafka is holding 5days of data or 50gb of data per topic. Or your kafka is not configured to keep data, or your spout consumers are reading from the now() point and not from the offset where they stopped.

Comment: My problem is that I deleted  zookeeper_server.pid when I could not stop zookeeper process. Now I chmod of  zookeeper_server.pid file instead of deletion, now everything works ok. I will still make a question in a new thread, because there are many configurations files in Kafka storm back bone. I need a clear picture what is what.